Why do the roots of $\int_0^x (1-s^2)^n ds$ lie on a lemniscate?
Consider the polynomial
$$f_n(x)=\int_0^x (1-s^2)^n ds$$
for some integer $n$. I am interested in these polynomials for reasons unrelated to this question: these are the odd polynomials of which the maximum possible number of derivatives vanish at $x=\pm 1$.
The first few such polynomials are
$$f_0(x)=x$$
$$f_1(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}$$
$$f_2(x)=x-\frac{2 x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}$$
$$f_3(x)=x-x^3+\frac{3 x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}$$
On a whim, I plotted the roots of these polynomials, I find that they all lie on a lemniscate. For example, for $n=50$,

I suspect there is some "limit lemniscate" as $n\rightarrow \infty$. This comes as a complete surprise to me. Why should the roots of these polynomials lie on a lemniscate, at all?

Looks like a double Szegö curve which is not crazy since $(1-(s/n)^2)^n\to e^{-s^2}$.

A remark (is it useful ?) This answer provides the following relationship : $f_n(x)=x(1-x^2)^n+2n(f_{n+1}(x)-f_{n-1}(x))$ which can be turned into a second-order recurrence relationship for the $f_n(x)$.

To be precise, the plot is of these roots in the complex plane.

Connected : https://akjournals.com/view/journals/10998/25/2/article-p179.xml https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/zeros-of-iterated-integrals-of-polynomials/3A3A64E1F67DC8B769A944F55135D236

One minor observation. Obviously, $x=0$ is always a root of $f_n(x)$. If we approximate in the neighborhood of zero, though, we get $f_n(x)\approx x-n x^3/3$. So for any finite $n$ we should expect to find no other zeros than $x=0$ in a neighborhood of radius $\sqrt{3/n}$. (Hence the large "excluded" zone around the origin for any finite $n$.)

A more interesting observation is that, according to Mathematica, this polynomial can be expressed as a hypergeometric function: $f_n(x)={2}F{1}(1/2,-n;3/2,x^2)$. (This hypergeometric function truncates for any nonnegative integer $n$ and is thus actually a polynomial.) Upon further experimentation, it appears that the zeros of ${2}F{1}(1/2,-n;3/2,1+z)$ converge to the unit circle in $z$ as $n\to\infty$. This is presumably equivalent to the lemniscate, but may be simpler to prove.

Is the claim that the roots of each polynomial in the sequence lie on a lemniscate or just the the limit of the curve on which they lie is a lemniscate? My numerical calculations suggest that the roots of $f_3$ and $f_4$, for instance, don't in fact lie on a lemniscate.

I don't have a specific type of lemniscate in mind. There are many kinds, and the roots do lie on figure-8 curves "lemniscates" not just in the limit but also for finite $n$, even $n=3$ or $n=4$. Why would the roots lie on a simple curve at all, as opposed to being scattered around the complex plane?


Fig. 1 : The roots of polynomial $f_{31}$ and the standard lemniscate with equ. $(x^2+y^2)^2=2(x^2-y^2)$. This figure has been  drawn with a  "SAGE" program (see remark at the bottom).
The remarkable last comments by @Semiclassical
$$\begin{cases}f_n(Z)&=&{_2}F_{1}(1/2,-n;3/2,Z^2)\color{red}{Z}\\
f_n(\sqrt{1-z})&=&{_2}F_{1}(1/2,-n;3/2,1+z)\color{red}{\sqrt{1-z}}\end{cases}$$
can be understood at the light of the following
Lemma : the (double) complex mapping defined by :
$$z \mapsto Z=\pm \sqrt{1+z} \ \iff \ Z^2=1+z\tag{1}$$
maps the unit circle $U$ onto the "unit lemniscate".
Proof of lemma : (1) is equivalent to
$$(Z-1)(Z+1)=z$$
Therefore, we have :
$$|Z-1| |Z+1|=|z|$$
As a consequence, constraining $z$ to be with modulus $1$ is equivalent to say that the product of distances of $Z$ to "foci" $-1$ and $+1$ is equal to constant $1$, which is one of the definitions of Bernoulli's lemniscate, as a particular case of Cassini ovals). $\square$

Fig. 2.
Now, it remains to establish that the roots of the second polynomial in (1) are closer and closer to the unit circle $U$ as examplified by figure 3 obtained using Wolfram Alpha (see Remark 3 below) in the case $n=15$ : not only are they close to $U$ but also close to the $n+1=16$th roots of unity. Therefore, the question remains open...

Fig. 3.
Remarks :

Fig. 1 has been drawn with the following "SAGE" program :
 from sage.functions.hypergeometric import closed_form
 var('x y')
 P = lambda n : simplify(closed_form(hypergeometric([1/2,-n],[3/2], x^2)))
 g=Graphics()
 L=[[0,0]]
 w=P(32)
 s=w.roots(ring=CDF)
 for k in range(len(s)) :
    u=s[k][0]
    L.append([real_part(u),imag_part(u)])
 g+=plot(point(L,color='red', xmin=-2,xmax=2, ymin = -1, ymax = 1, aspect_ratio=1))
 g+=implicit_plot((x^2+y^2)^2==2*(x^2-y^2),(x,-2,2),(y,-1,1))
 g+=plot(line(([-2,0],[2,0]),color='black'))
 g+=plot(line(([0,-1],[0,1]),color='black'))
 show(g)


Fig. 2 has been drawn using the following Matlab script :
 t=0:pi/100:2*pi;
 plot(1+exp(i*t));hold on;axis equal;
 for s=-1:2:1
    plot(s*sqrt(1+exp(i*t)));hold on;
 end;


Fig. 3 has been obtained with Wolfram Alpha by asking :


$$\text{roots (sqrt(1+x) 2F1(1/2, -15, 3/2, 1+x))}$$

Maybe the explicit formula can be written for the leminscate, like $z=f(x)+g(y) i$?

@Tyma Gaidash  I am not sure that such a formula exists. See my Edit for a kind of geometrical representation.

A beautiful answer, but then the question becomes "why do the roots of ${2}F{1}(1/2,-n;3/2,1+z)$ approach the unit circle for large $n$?"

I have modified my answer in order to take your remark into account.

It is probably valuable to explore Szegö curves as advised in the first comment and which I have met in an answer of mine here.

@underflow 1) I agree with your remarks. 2) Please write this "actual answer". I will be happy to see it and most probably upvote it.

@underflow Indeed, I was confusing you with user "semiclassical"

@semiclassical I would like to know, if it is possible, how you have found the amazing transformations you have given. A reason among others : doing some web search, I found a new way to answer a question to which I had already given an answer (conformal mapping of a disk onto a square ; see my today's edit here and this new way involves a hypergeometric function which is of the same type as yours... I don't know in articular if/how it can connected to the other transforms I had previously found...
